# Rotating list-group vertically in Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

simple html code works fine and shows a set of rows:

```
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-block">
    <ul class="list-group" role="group" aria-label="Basic example">
      <li class="rotated list-group-item d-flex">Primary</li>
      <li class="rotated list-group-item d-flex">Secondary</li>
      <li class="rotated list-group-item d-flex">Success</li>
      <li class="rotated list-group-item d-flex">Info</li>
      <li class="rotated list-group-item d-flex">Warning</li>
      <li class="rotated list-group-item d-flex">Danger</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

when I add the following css, the list items become vertical but all stacked on top of each other.

```
.rotated {
    -ms-transform: rotate(270deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform: rotate(270deg);
}
```

how can I fix this situation so the items appear correctly as columns rather than rows.
Thanks!

```css
.card-deck {
  height: 200px;
}

.rotated {
    -ms-transform: rotate(270deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform: rotate(270deg);
}
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
<div class="card-deck">
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-block">
    <ul class="list-group" role="group" aria-label="Basic example">
      <li class="rotated list-group-item d-flex">Primary</li>
      <li class="rotated list-group-item d-flex">Secondary</li>
      <li class="rotated list-group-item d-flex">Success</li>
      <li class="rotated list-group-item d-flex">Info</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

just figured this out. I moved the rotated class to the list-group instead :)

```
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-block">
    <ul class="rotated list-group" role="group" aria-label="Basic example">
      <li class="list-group-item d-flex">Primary</li>
      <li class="list-group-item d-flex">Secondary</li>
      <li class="list-group-item d-flex">Success</li>
      <li class="list-group-item d-flex">Info</li>
      <li class="list-group-item d-flex">Warning</li>
      <li class="list-group-item d-flex">Danger</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```